# check whether username exists or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a registration page where when the user enters his email id, its being "verified whether he is already a registered user or not".

i tried writing the code in the textchange event of the textbox but it did not work.
during runtime it does not calls the textchange event of the textbox.

```
 obj.LocalConnection_Class(con);
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select COUNT(*) from SUBSCRIBER_MASTER where emailId ='" + txtEmail.Text + "'";
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
```

can anyone tell me how can i make it work.

Comment: have you set AutoPostBack to True of textbox

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve you should probably do this check on the postback of the page. There is only a box "Email address" + submit button. Then after submitting you check for existence. If it already exists do X and otherwise Y.

Comment: The [TextChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx) is raised when the content of the text box changes between *posts* to the server. If you want to check while they type, you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: Please read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth is correct, the injection vulnerability needs to be addressed above all else. Also, this should be an `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteReader()` as all that's being returned is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set TextBox AutoPostBack Property to true

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcheck" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  Ontextchanged="txtcheck_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To call Textbox Change Event you should add this "`AutoPostBack`" attribute to your textbox tag and set it to `True`

so your Textbox Tag look like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```